# Как проверить http запрос на 200

Tags: php, http, curl

Доброго времени суток, подскажите как в php проверить ответ cURL запрос, нужно отсеять всё кроме  ответа 200 ОК

Comment: Проверить через if else если у ответа номер 200 ОК то всё окей, если другие номера то срабатывает else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делается это след. образом:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true); // не получать контент

$httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); // получить статус код
```